# Using FOR JSON and CTE and store it in a variable

Tags: json, t-sql, common-table-expression

How can I generate a JSON in T-SQL using `FOR JSON` from a select statement that uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) and then store it in a local variable?
Without a CTE it could look like this:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT  x.Val
    FROM (VALUES (1)) AS x(Val)
    FOR JSON AUTO
)
SELECT @var
```

But how ist the syntax if a CTE is in used like the following?

```
WITH y AS (
    SELECT  Val
    FROM (VALUES (1)) AS _(Val)
)
SELECT  x.Val, y.Val ValY
FROM (VALUES (1)) AS x(Val)
JOIN y ON y.Val = x.Val
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Surrounding with `DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(MAX) = ( ... )` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be something like this?

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH y AS (
    SELECT  Val
    FROM (VALUES (1)) AS _(Val)
)
SELECT @json=
(
    SELECT  x.Val, y.Val ValY
    FROM (VALUES (1)) AS x(Val)
    JOIN y ON y.Val = x.Val
    FOR JSON AUTO
);

SELECT @json;
```

Additionally you can place a CTE as a sub-query instead of the "WITH". The CTE is not much more than "syntactic sugar" actually to avoid repeated sub-queries and to get your SQL better readable. You can use this for the same:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT  x.Val, y.Val ValY
    FROM (VALUES (1)) AS x(Val)
    JOIN (
            SELECT  Val
            FROM (VALUES (1)) AS _(Val)
         ) y ON y.Val = x.Val
    FOR JSON AUTO
);

SELECT @json
```

Comment: I've had to read the question twice before I realized your answer is probably correct...

Comment: Ah, i tried this solution with SET instead of SELECT, which didn't work. Thank! The code in my question just was an example. In the real thing I used the CTE to avoid repeationg the same sub-querie, as you mantioned.